# How to configure Spring Data REST to return the representation of the resource created for a POST request?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-jpa

I am following the spring-data-rest guide [Accessing JPA Data with REST](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/). When I http post a new record it is inserted (and the response is a 201). That is great, but is there a way to configure the REST MVC code to return the newly created object? I'd rather not have to send a search request to find the new instance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't have to search for the created entity. As the HTTP spec suggests, `POST` requests returning a status code of `201 Created` are supposed to contain a `Location` header which contains the URI of the resource just created.

Thus all you need to do is effectively issuing a `GET` request to that particular URI. Spring Data REST also has two methods on `RepositoryRestConfiguration.setReturnBodyOnCreate(…)` and `….setReturnBodyOnUpdate(…)` which you can use to configure the framework to immediately return  the representation of the resource just created.

Comment: Based on this question, I have actually updated ALL of the Spring Data REST getting started guides to include this information, so you don't have to come here to discover the feature.

Comment: @gregturn I think this is exactly the solution I've been looking for.

Comment: Excellent! I remember reading about it but when I started testing I forgot where to look.

Comment: Where should RepositoryRestConfiguration.setReturnBodyOnCreate(true) be called?

Answer (score 12):

Example with Spring Boot:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        RepositoryRestConfiguration restConfiguration = ctx.getBean(RepositoryRestConfiguration.class);

        restConfiguration.setReturnBodyOnCreate(true);
    }
}
```

or

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        super.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config);
        config.setReturnBodyOnCreate(true);
    }
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: configureRepositoryRestConfiguration  deprecated...since 2.4, implement RepositoryRestConfigurer.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration) either directly or extend RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter and override the method.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Spring Boot, you can add the following lines to your `application.properties` file for `POST` (create) and `PUT` (update) respectively

```
spring.data.rest.return-body-on-create=true
spring.data.rest.return-body-on-update=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another variant that uses DI rather than extending RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration or using the ConfigurableApplicationContext.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);    
    }

    @Autowired private RepositoryRestConfiguration repositoryRestConfiguration;

    @PostConstruct
    public void exposeIds() {
        this.repositoryRestConfiguration.setReturnBodyForPutAndPost(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: is this alternative any better then Andrey's solution, or it's really just an alternative? I mean, is there any gain using either of them?