# Hibernate PreInsertEventListener modified fields show up as null in Spring Boot Repository POST response JSON

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I implemented `org.hibernate.event.spi.PreInsertEventListener` interface to populate common fields such as *createdTime*, *modifiedTime*, etc. in my entities. I also use Spring Boot Data Repository interfaces to handle `REST` methods.

`POST` method to create an entity (E.g., User) is working fine and the User details are getting persisted in the tables. The request body is:

```
{
    "login": "nagu2",
    "password": "123456",
    "displayName": "Nagu 2",
    "preferences": "Test",
    "userProfile": {
        "firstName": "Nagarajan"
    },
    "userStatus": "USERSTATUS_ACTIVE"
}
```

However, the Body of the 201 response contains a null value for the fields populated using `PreInsertEventListener`. The response body is:\

```
{
  "createdTime": null,
  "updatedTime": null,
  "createdBy": null,
  "updatedBy": null,
  "tenant": 1,
  "login": "nagu2",
  "password": "123456",
  "displayName": "Nagu 2",
  "preferences": "Test",
  "userRoles": null,
  "userProfile": {
    "createdTime": null,
    "updatedTime": null,
    "createdBy": null,
    "updatedBy": null,
    "tenant": 1,
    "firstName": "Nagarajan",
    "middleName": null,
    "lastName": null,
    "dateOfBirth": null,
    "timeZone": null,
    "primaryPhone": null,
    "secondaryPhone": null,
    "primaryEmail": null,
    "secondaryEmail": null
  },
  "lastLoginTime": null,
  "userStatus": "USERSTATUS_ACTIVE",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/user/6"
    },
    "user": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/user/6"
    }
  }
}
```

If I `GET` the Location URL of the 201 response, I do get all the fields populated with non-null values. The GET response of the Location URL is:

```
{
  "createdTime": "2019-12-07T11:29:50.000+0000",
  "updatedTime": "2019-12-07T11:29:50.000+0000",
  "createdBy": 1,
  "updatedBy": 1,
  "tenant": 1,
  "login": "nagu2",
  "password": "123456",
  "displayName": "Nagu 2",
  "preferences": "Test",
  "userRoles": [],
  "userProfile": {
    "createdTime": "2019-12-07T11:29:50.000+0000",
    "updatedTime": "2019-12-07T11:29:50.000+0000",
    "createdBy": 1,
    "updatedBy": 1,
    "tenant": 1,
    "firstName": "Nagarajan",
    "middleName": null,
    "lastName": null,
    "dateOfBirth": null,
    "timeZone": null,
    "primaryPhone": null,
    "secondaryPhone": null,
    "primaryEmail": null,
    "secondaryEmail": null
  },
  "lastLoginTime": null,
  "userStatus": "USERSTATUS_ACTIVE",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/user/5"
    },
    "user": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/user/5"
    }
  }
}
```

Setting `RepositoryRestConfiguration.setReturnBodyOnCreate` to *true* as suggested [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775387/how-to-configure-spring-data-rest-to-return-the-representation-of-the-resource-c) did not help too.

Can you please help me with a way to return non-null values for the *PreInsertEventListener-modified-fields* in the 201 response of the POST request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following point from [This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595727/change-entity-using-hibernate-preinserteventlistener) and [this blog post](http://anshuiitk.blogspot.com/2010/11/hibernate-pre-database-opertaion-event.html)

> If you have insert and update actions on your entity in one single
>   transaction, then your preInsert listener actions will be overridden
>   by the update action.

helped me resolve the issue.

Point to be noted here is that:

In `onPreInsert` method, when I updated only the values in `Object[] state`, it caused both `insert` and `update` query to fire. However, **when I set the values in both Object[] state and the entity (event.getEntity()), hibernate fired only the insert query** and 201 response JSON contains non-null values.

Following is the modified `onPreInsert` implementation:

```
public boolean onPreInsert(PreInsertEvent event) {
    if (event.getEntity() instanceof BaseEntity) {
        Object obj = event.getEntity();
        BaseEntity entity = (BaseEntity) obj;
        boolean isMultiTenant = event.getEntity() instanceof BaseMultiTenantEntity;
        Object[] state = event.getState();
        String[] propertyNames = event.getPersister().getEntityMetamodel().getPropertyNames();

        Date createdTime = new Date();
        entity.setCreatedTime(createdTime);
        setValue(state, propertyNames, CREATED_TIME_PROPERTY, createdTime);

        Integer createdBy = getUserId();
        entity.setCreatedBy(createdBy);
        setValue(state, propertyNames, CREATED_BY_PROPERTY, createdBy);

        entity.setUpdatedTime(createdTime);
        setValue(state, propertyNames, UPDATED_TIME_PROPERTY, createdTime);

        entity.setUpdatedBy(createdBy);
        setValue(state, propertyNames, UPDATED_BY_PROPERTY, createdBy);

        if (isMultiTenant) {
            BaseMultiTenantEntity multiTenantEntity = (BaseMultiTenantEntity) obj;
            multiTenantEntity.setTenant(getTenant());
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```